# pyspark break row to multiple rows

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to accomplish the following in PYSPARK. Sample source is provided below. We will be having more number of records in source.

Source:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Use text formatting instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `stack`function:

Setup of your example data:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(COLA='H', COLB='I', COLC='J',
        COL_GRP_A_1=0.1, COL_GRP_A_2=1., COL_GRP_A_3=3.,
        COL_GRP_B_1=4., COL_GRP_B_2=2.5, COL_GRP_B_3=6.,
        COL_GRP_C_1=2., COL_GRP_C_2=5., COL_GRP_C_3=4.,
       ),
])
df.show()
# Output
+----+----+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|COLA|COLB|COLC|COL_GRP_A_1|COL_GRP_A_2|COL_GRP_A_3|COL_GRP_B_1|COL_GRP_B_2|COL_GRP_B_3|COL_GRP_C_1|COL_GRP_C_2|COL_GRP_C_3|
+----+----+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   H|   I|   J|        0.1|        1.0|        3.0|        4.0|        2.5|        6.0|        2.0|        5.0|        4.0|
+----+----+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Now the processing:

```py
(
    df
    .selectExpr(
        'COLA', 'COLB', 'COLC',
        'stack(3, "COL_GRP_A", COL_GRP_A_1, COL_GRP_A_2, COL_GRP_A_3, "COL_GRP_B", COL_GRP_B_1, COL_GRP_B_2, COL_GRP_B_3, "COL_GRP_C", COL_GRP_C_1, COL_GRP_C_2, COL_GRP_C_3) AS (GRP, COL_VAL1, COL_VAL2, COL_VAL3)'
    )
    .show()
)
# Output:
+----+----+----+---------+--------+--------+--------+
|COLA|COLB|COLC|      GRP|COL_VAL1|COL_VAL2|COL_VAL3|
+----+----+----+---------+--------+--------+--------+
|   H|   I|   J|COL_GRP_A|     0.1|     1.0|     3.0|
|   H|   I|   J|COL_GRP_B|     4.0|     2.5|     6.0|
|   H|   I|   J|COL_GRP_C|     2.0|     5.0|     4.0|
+----+----+----+---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks.. Any way to keep COLA,COLB & COLC as only one row, others should be empty. Like i shown in  expected output.

Comment: @Raja: There are several ways to do this. The easiest would probably be to delete the content of the row that should be empty: `.withColumn('COLA', F.when(F.col('GRP') == 'COL_GRP_A', F.col('COLA')))` and so on.
Your use case is a mystery to me though :)

Comment: Thanks..how can we do the same in python pandas dataframe.